# How can I extract numbers as well as string from multiple rows in a Data Frame column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

**DF1**

```
index|Number
0    |[Number 1]
1    |[Number 2]
2    |[kg]
3    |[]
4    |[kg,Number 3]
```

In my dataframe in the `Number` column, I need to extract the number if present, `kg` if the string has `kg` and `NaN` if there is no value. If the row has both the number and `kg` then I will extract only the number.

**Expected Output**

```
index|Number
0    |1
1    |2
2    |kg
3    |NaN
4    |3
```

I wrote a lambda function for this but I am getting Error

```
NumorKG = lambda x: x.str.extract('(\d+)') if x.str.extract('(\d+)').isdigit() else 'kg' if x.str.find('kg') else "NaN"

DF1['Number']=DF1['Number'].apply(NumorKG)
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: Is your `Number` column `list` or `str` ?

Comment: I believe `apply` works on each element in the `Series` element-wise. (You are getting the error because the input for lambda (`x`) are each string in `DF1['Number']`). Instead of using `apply`, `NumorKG(DF1['Number'])` should work if your lambda is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set values:

```
#extract numeric to Series
d = df['Number'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
#test if digit
mask1 = d.str.isdigit().fillna(False)
```

#test if values contains kg
    mask2 = df['Number'].str.contains('kg', na=False)

```
df['Number'] = np.where(mask1, d, 
               np.where(mask2 & ~mask1, 'kg',np.nan))
print (df)
  Number
0      1
1      2
2     kg
3    nan
4      3
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
import re

def NumorKG(x):
    a = re.findall('(\d+)', x)
    if len(a) > 0:
        return a[0]
    elif 'kg' in x:
        return 'kg'

    else:
        return np.nan

df['Number']=df['Number'].apply(NumorKG)
print (df)
  Number
0      1
1      2
2     kg
3    NaN
4      3
```

And your lambda function should be changed:

```
NumorKG = lambda x: re.findall('(\d+)', x)[0] 
                    if len(re.findall('(\d+)', x)) > 0 
                    else 'kg' 
                    if 'kg' in x 
                    else np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

In `apply`, what is returned is a scalar, so you can't use the .str accessor.

As you are dealing with only one column, no need for apply.

As an alternative to Jezrael (that would be reproducible), this is a possible solution:

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [["Number 1"], ["Number 2"], ["kg"], [""], ["kg", "Number 3"]]})
DF1['Number'] = DF1.Number.str.join(sep=" ")


mask_digit = DF1.Number.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).str.isdigit().fillna(False)
mask_kg = DF1['Number'].str.contains('kg', na=False)

DF1.loc[mask_digit, 'Number'] = DF1.Number.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
DF1.loc[mask_kg,'Number'] = 'kg'
DF1.loc[~(mask_digit | mask_kg), 'Number'] = np.NaN
```